# Cannot convert lambda expression to type because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#, compiler-errors, delegates

I'm a beginner with C# and recently I've learned about the Breadth-First Search algorithm so I try to write it with C#. Here is my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Data.Entity;

public class Node
    {
        public string NodeName { get; set; }
        public bool visited { get; set; }
        public LinkedList<Node> _item;
        public Node()
        {
            _item = new LinkedList<Node>();
        }
       public LinkedList<Node> Child { get { return _item; } set { _item = value; } }
    }
 public static class NodeExtension
    {  
       public static void BFS(this Node root, string name)
       {
            Node result = n.Child.Find(x => x.NodeName == "name"); 
            foreach(var item in n.Child)
            {
                item.visited = false;
            }
            Queue<Node> queue = new Queue<Node>();
            root.visited = true;
            queue.Enqueue(root);
            while(queue.Any())
            {
                result = queue.First();
                Console.WriteLine(result.NodeName);
                queue.Dequeue();
            }

            LinkedList<Node> list = n.Child;
            foreach(var v in list)
            {
                if(!v.visited)
                {
                    v.visited = true;
                    queue.Enqueue(v);
                }
            }
       }
    }
```

But then I get an error message "Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'Node' because it is not a delegate type" from this line:

```
Node result = n.Child.Find(x => x.NodeName == "name");
```

Can someone help me explain the meaning of this message and how to solve it and if there is any problem with my function please also help me point that out, much appreciate it!

Comment: The error message refers to the correct usage of the `.Find()` function. If you check your IntelliSense (or the documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.linkedlist-1.find?view=net-7.0), it says that you need to pass in a variable of type `Node` as the argument, not a predicate. If you want to use a predicate, you could try `n.Child.Where(x => x.NodeName == "name").FirstOrDefault();`

Comment: (There is also an [overload of `.FirstOrDefault()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.firstordefault?view=net-7.0#system-linq-enumerable-firstordefault-1(system-collections-generic-ienumerable((-0))-system-func((-0-system-boolean))-0)) that takes a predicate as an input parameter, so the suggestion could be simplified to: `n.Child.FirstOrDefault(x => x.NodeName == "name");`).